# Modify custom object page to show all records from parent client

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, list-view

I have a custom object (Service_Orders__c) in my Customer Portal which allows customers to create/view orders they have made.
As these users belong to a parent client, is it possible to modify the view pages so that they can view orders from all users from the parent client as apposed to just their own orders.
(preferably without making a custom vf page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this if you are using the enterprise customer portal admin license, as this allows the portal users to participate in sharing rules.  When you add an account to the portal, this will create roles in the hierarchy.

You can then set up a sharing rule to share Service_Orders__c records owned by Portal Roles and Subordinates of the " Customer Executive" role with Portal Roles and Subordinates of the " Customer Executive" role. Below is a screenshot from one of my dev orgs:

[image]

I choose "BrightGen Customer Executive" for each of Step 3 and 4, which means that whenever any BrightGen employee creates a case it is shared with all the other BrightGen employees.  We use this technique on our customer portal to give visibility of all cases for a customer to all of their employees that have a portal login.

Once this rule is in place, any user on the portal accessing the 'All Service Orders' list view will be able to see their colleague's records.

Comment: Bob, I do have an Enterprise license. Do you have any links to further information about this and how to set it up?

Comment: Unfortunately the help doesn't have a huge amount of information around this.  That said there's not much to it - just create sharing rules for the portal roles associated with each account that will have access to your portal.

Comment: What page in SF can I find these options?

Comment: Setup -> Security Controls -> Sharing Settings.  If you aren't familiar with this, I'd strongly suggest you have a read of the help, as you are opening up your data externally.

Comment: Sorry to bring up a completed question, I have only got round to trying to enable this feature. Reading what you have suggested in your post, it appears that the users in question must share the same Role type. As almost all my Customer portal users have the same Role has can this be acheived? I have over 200 clients so I do not want to give each client a different role name.

Comment: The platform creates roles automatically, based on the account that the customer portal users are associated with. That would imply your customer portal users are all parented by the same account - is that the case, or are you thinking of profiles as opposed to roles?

Comment: Nevermind I got it working :-)